# My 2-node hadoop performing better than my 4-node hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm running some jobs on Hive: first with a 4-node and then a 2-node. To my surprise, my 2-node  performs better than my 4-node.

First I run the queries on a 4-node (4 live nodes) and then I shut down 2 nodes (2 live nodes) and run same thing..

Any ideas?
Thanks,

Comment: Can you share more details about your environment setup and the workloads you're running?

Comment: 4 node virtual cluster with the default configuration. i can run my mapreduce jobs. my admin page, 50070, indicates i have 4 live nodes. the work load is ~ 200MB of text.

Comment: When you say virtual cluster, is it running on the same machine? How powerful are the VMs and is the physical machine able to support all the VMs?

Comment: I'm using the default configuration, basically.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the clarification comments, it sounds like you're running multiple vms on a single machine. Hadoop is not designed to run this way. For anything beyond basic functional testing, you should set up a real cluster with real hardware or use something like EC2.

The reason why your performance goes up by reducing the number of nodes is because you have less "machines" competing for the same resources.

Comment: Yes, I have a single machine with 8 cores but I have allocated just 1 cpu for each virtual machine so that no resource competing is there.

Comment: You must keep in mind that there is also an SO using the other cores, and possibly some programs in background. Aside from that, more cores is more disk writting/memory allocation competition.

Comment: That's correct... there might not be CPU contention, but if you have only one disk, there will be i/o contention. Regardless, Hadoop is not meant to be run on VMs on a single machine... It is possible to set it up. VMWare has white paper on how to do this and it's not easy. You should either do a bare metal setup using multiple servers or use EMR or run your own Hadoop distro on AWS.